# delete from selected datagridview

Tags: c#

```
private void gridselect(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    chooseAnyRow = e.RowIndex;
    DataGridViewRow row = bndisplay.Rows[chooseAnyRow];
    textBox1.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
}

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow deleterow = bndisplay.Rows[chooseAnyRow];

    deleterow.Cells[5].Value = textBox1.Text;

    /*com = con.CreateCommand();
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "delete from candidateRegistration where icnumber = '' " + textBox1.Text;
    */

    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand com;
    string connstring = @"Data Source=dasranrajlui\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SESoriginal;Integrated Security=True";

    con = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    con.Open();
    string sqlstr = "delete from candidateRegistration where icnumber= " + textBox1.Text;

    sqlstr = sqlstr + "" + textBox1.Text + ")";

    com = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, con);

    try
    {
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("deleted...");

        textBox1.Text = null;
    }

    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(EX + "NOT deleted");
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

ok i have edited the code but now im getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x801319404) : incorrect syntax
>   near ')'.....

Comment: You really 'need the database from sql to be removed'?? are you sure?

Comment: try commenting out the first `con.Open();` line

Comment: Not only that.... first he opens con, then defines conn, opens conn, finally closes con...totally CONfusing..

Comment: @DasranRajlui which line throws the exception?

Comment: there are many code confusion `con.Open();` `com.ExecuteNonQuery();` concat of `sqlstr` !!

Comment: Remove  `")"` in  `sqlstr = sqlstr + "" + textBox1.Text + ")";`  Why you use this concat ?

Answer (score 0):

You have no object named "com" declared 
change `com.ExecuteNonQuery();`  to `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Probably he has defined com elsewhere just like the con and conn...the fix you recommended, would have been for a compilation error..

Answer (score 0):

Refer This.It may Help You.

[Delete Row from Gridview using Link Button Click in Asp.net with Confirmation](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/11/delete-row-from-gridview-using-link-button-click-in-aspnet-with-confirmation.html)

[Grid view row deleting event using asp.net c #](http://csharpexample.com/CsharpExampleSeeDetail.aspx?Did=10&CatID=21)